# Python - Main() loop not executing repeatedly

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

(New to Python and trying my best)

This program runs, and the buttons do the right things.  But the MAIN() procedure block doesn't work.  I'm wanting main() to keep looping until the user closes the program.  Within the loop is a simple decision about a time comparison and if 10 seconds have elapsed the 3 buttons will get a light grey background.

I tried some print statements within the main() area and they don't print at all.  Where am I going wrong?

Thanks a bunch

```
from guizero import App, Text, TextBox, PushButton
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import time
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

# This procedure will watch three inputs and lock in the team that calls in first for 5seconds
# Change the colors of the buttons to show which team pressed in first.


def action1(dunno):
        # Team1 button pressed
        global SetCurrTime
        if datetime.now() > SetCurrTime + timedelta(seconds=5):
                # Mark Team 1 as the buzzer beater
                team1_btn.bg="green"
                team2_btn.bg="red"
                team3_btn.bg="red"
                SetCurrTime = datetime.now()
                txtButtons_Hit.value = "Team1 was hit: " + str(SetCurrTime)

def action2(dunno):
        # Team2 button pressed
        global SetCurrTime
        if datetime.now() > SetCurrTime + timedelta(seconds=5):
                # Mark Team 2 as the buzzer beater
                team1_btn.bg="red"
                team2_btn.bg="green"
                team3_btn.bg="red"
                SetCurrTime = datetime.now()
                txtButtons_Hit.value = "Team2 was hit: " + str(SetCurrTime)


def action3(dunno):
        # Team3 button pressed
        global SetCurrTime
        if datetime.now() > SetCurrTime + timedelta(seconds=5):
                # Mark Team 3 as the buzzer beater
                team1_btn.bg="red"
                team2_btn.bg="red"
                team3_btn.bg="green"
                SetCurrTime = datetime.now()
                txtButtons_Hit.value = "Team3 was hit: " + str(SetCurrTime)


def main():
        #reset board when 5seconds has elapsed from SetCurrTime
        app.display()
        global SetCurrTime
        print ("Here")
        while True:
                txtButtons_Hit.value = "Current Time: " + str(datetime.now())
                print ("here")
                if datetime.now() > SetCurrTime + timedelta(seconds=5):
                        # clear the board
                        team1_btn.bg="light grey"
                        team2_btn.bg="light grey"
                        team3_btn.bg="light grey"


# Pin setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # Broadcom pin-numbering scheme
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.RISING, callback=action1, bouncetime=1800)
GPIO.add_event_detect(20, GPIO.RISING, callback=action2, bouncetime=1800)
GPIO.add_event_detect(21, GPIO.RISING, callback=action3, bouncetime=1800)

SetCurrTime = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=-5) #init this at the start of the program


app = App(title="A07 DSS Tri-State - Jeopardy", width=700)
blank1 = Text(app, text="")
welcome_message = Text(app, text="This..      is..       Jeopardy!!", size=30, font="Times New Roman", color="blue")

blank2 = Text(app, text="")
blank3 = Text(app, text="")

team1_btn = PushButton(app, text="Team Black & Blue", command = lambda:action1(1))
team1_btn.bg="light grey"
blank4 = Text(app, text="")
team2_btn = PushButton(app, text="Team Holiday Spirit", command=lambda:action2(2))
team2_btn.bg="light grey"
blank5 = Text(app, text="")
team3_btn = PushButton(app, text="Team Creamsicle", command=lambda:action3(3))
team3_btn.bg="light grey"
blank6 = Text(app, text="")
delay_timer = Text(app, text="0")
delay_timer.visible=False
blank7 = Text(app, text="")
txtButtons_Hit = Text(app, text="Current Time: " + str(SetCurrTime))


main()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"?  What actually happens?  What did you expect to happen?  Can you provide the program output?...

Comment: How do you execute your program? Is this content in a file, say `myprog.py` and you do `python myprog.py`?

Comment: Bill - The GUI screen comes up and the button subroutines work just fine.  It seems the statements in the main() subroutine don't do anything.  The print commands that were added to help troubleshoot don't print. The while loop doesn't seem to keep looping and certainly do not reset the buttons to a light grey color after they have been set to red or green by the other subroutines.

Comment: Sush - I've got the .py program file open and hit the 'run' menu and then 'run module'.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the program

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I added this to the bottom in place of main() line and nothing changed.  The form still comes up and acts the same as before.

Comment: Hmmm So I just noticed the print ("Here") command is outputing to the shell, but only after closing the app window (my custom form).

Comment: I'm not sure as I'm new to this.. I thought the print stuff would happen real time to the shell.   But honestly I don't care about the print items, I would like some feedback on what could be fouling up the main() loop from resetting the colors of the buttons.  Can you help identify that?